# Vue: webpack is not loading css in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack, webpacker

I am using webpack in Vue+Rails project.

My problem is when i am working in development mode all css works fine but in production the css does,'t loaded as you can see in below image.

[image]

as shown in image the css is not loading in webpack

my webpack folder contains these code

environment.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
// const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const vue = require('./loaders/vue')

// environment.plugins.prepend('VueLoaderPlugin', new VueLoaderPlugin())
environment.plugins.append(
  'VueLoaderPlugin',
  new VueLoaderPlugin()
);
environment.loaders.append('vue', vue)

environment.plugins.append(
  'Globals', // arbitrary name
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    _: 'underscore'
  })
);

module.exports = environment
```

vue.js which is for loader
the vue.js file is imported in environment.js as `const vue = require('./loaders/vue')`

vue.js

```
module.exports = {
      test: /\.vue(\.erb)?$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      }]
    }
```

and
    production.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

and
package.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "ckeditor4-vue": "^0.1.0",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "fibers": "^4.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "sass": "^1.25.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-loader": "^15.8.3",
    "vue-lodash": "^2.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-timeago": "^5.1.2",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

these are the webpack configuration that i have used.
as shown is above image the css for webpack is not loading in production. It is working in development but not in production

EDIT:

I run this command then `RAILS_ENV=production rails s -p 3000`
logs after loading the landing page

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 6.0.3 application starting in production http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
[2020-06-15 19:46:30] INFO  WEBrick 1.4.2
[2020-06-15 19:46:30] INFO  ruby 2.6.3 (2019-04-16) [x86_64-darwin18]
[2020-06-15 19:46:30] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=45667 port=3000
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020:19:46:34 IST] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 3571
- -> /login
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020:19:46:34 IST] "GET /packs/js/application-0ea0a86691fc31d5032d.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
http://0.0.0.0:3000/login -> /packs/js/application-0ea0a86691fc31d5032d.js
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2020:19:46:34 IST] "GET /packs/js/application-0ea0a86691fc31d5032d.js.map HTTP/1.1" 304 0
- -> /packs/js/application-0ea0a86691fc31d5032d.js.map
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your logs? If so, could you post those logs? For example, I've noticed issues when I have `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` in my layout file, but the logs would help us figure out the exact issue

Comment: @UmarGhouse  added logs in the question and i am not using  `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> `

Comment: Interesting. I don't see any errors - have you tried running it *with* the `stylesheet_pack_tag`?

Comment: I didn't added `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag  %>` in my code. Now it is working. thanks @UmarGhouse

Comment: Hey no problem! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added this code in my layout file

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

and it worked. without this the css doesn't not loaded while deployed to production.